# FOREIGN KEY ON DELETE SET NULL

Tags: mysql, popsql

I am trying to create table but keep getting following error on last line at foreign key. Please help:

```
CREATE TABLE branch_supplier(
branch_id INT,
supplier_name VARCHAR(40),
supply_type VARCHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY(branch_id, supplier_name),
FOREIGN KEY(branch_id)REFERENCES branch(branch_id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

Failed

> ER_FK_COLUMN_NOT_NULL: Column 'branch_id' cannot be NOT NULL: needed
>   in a foreign key constraint 'branch_supplier_ibfk_1' SET NULL

Trying to create a new table in mysql and setting up foreign key.

Answer (score 3):

> A PRIMARY KEY is a unique index where all key columns must be defined as NOT NULL.

You define `branch_id` as nullable. But that is not allowed because it is part of the primary key.

Comment: I am new in sql and trying to learn through a on-line video. I copied the same what ever it is showing in video and not sure what I am missing. would you please let me know what should I write.(full command). Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Remove the `ON DELETE SET NULL` part

Answer (score 0):

remove "on delete set null" part it works

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "on delete set null" use
foreign key(branch_id) references branch(branch_id) on delete cascade;
This clears the error as branch_id is a primary key. Cascade delete the child data once the parent is deleted.